# Selecting tag shows no tagged games

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

I was attempting to tag surf, so I clicked on the cs-global-offensive tag. It redirected me to the bounty page for that tag. [Click here to see if you can reproduce.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-go) I tried some other tags, and they all emulate this behavior no matter which tab is selected at the top.

Comment: sidenote: how do you format the tags to look like tags in questions and answers?

Comment: Use `[tag:tagname]` for [tag:tagname], and `[meta-tag:tagname]` for Meta tags.

Comment: Aaaaand the situation just resolved itself. I restarted the browser and it works properly now. Should I put that as an answer?

Comment: @BillyMailman thanks.

Comment: @Turtleweezard I'd just delete the question since the issue resolved itself in within a few minutes.

Comment: @Billy - we can [meta-tag] meta tags?!?! [Mind=Blown](http://i.imgur.com/j74SykU.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing some weirdness with the tags (apart the fact that tags are weird) will happen today while they <strike>break</strike> fix some old code.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212920/213575